# How to convert byte to int?

Tags: c, arduino

I have an Arduino which is reading in a set of three bytes from a program which correspond to degrees in which an actuator must turn.  I need to convert these bytes into integers so I can pass those integers on to my actuators.

For example, I know the default rest state value I receive from the program is 127.  I wrote a C# program to interpret these bytes and that can get them to a single integer value.  However, I am unable to figure out how to do this in the Arduino environment with C. I have tried typecasting each byte to a char and storing that in a string.  However that returns garbled values that make no sense.

```
void loop() {
 if(Serial.available() && sw)
 {
  for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
  {
    input[j] = Serial.read();
  }
  //command = ((String)input).toInt();
  sw = 0;

}

String myString = String((char *)input);

Serial.println(myString);
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The return value of `Serial.read()` is an `int`. Therefore, if you have the following code snippet:

   ```cpp
   int input[3];

   for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
     input[i] = Serial.read();
   }
   ```

   Then `input` should store three `int`s. However, the code:

   ```cpp
   char* input[3];

   for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    input[i] = Serial.read();
   }
   ```

   Will just store the byte conversion from `int` to `char`.
2. If you want to store this as a string, you need to do a proper conversion. In this case, use `itoa` (see [Arduino API description](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/PrintingNumbers)).

   The code snippet would be:

   ```cpp
   #include <stdlib>
   char* convertedString = itoa(input[i]);
   ```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
int command = input[0]*256*256 + input[1]*256 + input[2];
```

By the way the default language you use to program your an Arduino is C++, not C. Although they have some similarities.

Answer (score 2):

Below logic will help you

```
iDst = (cSrc[0] << 16) | (cSrc[1] << 8) | cSrc[2]
```

or else you can use union for this case

```
union byte2char
{
    char c[4];
    int i;
};
```

But union implementation needs to consider little and big endian systems

Comment: I would suggest to use "int16_t" instead of int - dependent on which architecture the program is being compiled on / for, int could be int8, int16, int32 or int64.